# Tkinter: Iterate Menubar Items with a unique argument in each command

Tags: python, tkinter, iteration, menubar

I want to create a list of files which a user can open inside the menu bar of my program. In this example the options list is just a list of strings, but in my actual program, the list is sourced from primary keys from a database. Since the database is always changing, I need to iterate through the keys and set the command to insert the respective text for each key.

Despite it iterating properly and not giving any errors, it does not fill the data correctly. Instead of filling in the key as expected, it always fills the last key in the iteration.

For example, if I click "File 1", then the entry field should display "File 1". Same goes for clicking "File 2". Instead, all three options output "File 3". I'm struggling to find a workaround. Is there any way to make this work. See the sample code below.

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()

menubar = Menu(root)
root.config(menu=menubar)



def insert_text(user_text): 
    entry_field.delete(0, 'end')
    entry_field.insert(0, user_text)
    
entry_field = Entry(root, width=50)
entry_field.pack()

submenu = Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
menubar.add_cascade(label="File", menu=submenu)

openmenu = Menu(submenu, tearoff=0)
submenu.add_cascade(label="Open", menu=openmenu)

file_menu = ['File 1', 'File 2', 'File 3']

#iterates through the string list. 
for file in file_menu:
    #each command should trigger with the respective file value
    openmenu.add_command(label = file, command = lambda: insert_text(file))

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You meant to assign to the command parameter like this: `command = lambda file=file: insert_text(file)`